# OctoberCMS Blog plugin with Recent post

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a strange requirement from the client. I am using OctoberCMS Blog plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-blog and its working as per my expectations.

However, I have a section called **Recent Post** in which I am showing 1 latest recent post and a blog listing in the same page with blogs list with latest coming as first blog.

Now my client is saying, the blog in **Recent Post** is same as first blog which is a latest blog, which is obviously the same.

Hence I used Twig's slice function https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html to hide/remove first blog from the list. Here is how I did it.

```
 {% if this.page.id == 'blog' %}
    {% if posts.currentPage == 1 %}
      {% set sliceBlogs = 1 %}
    {% else  %}
      {% set sliceBlogs = 0 %}
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    {% set sliceBlogs = 0 %}
  {% endif %}
```

`{% for post in posts | slice(sliceBlogs) %}`

Here as you can see, I have made a condition, If Only blog listing page is found and also first page is found, then only it will hide/remove first blog from the blog list.

But here I am having issues at `Post per page`. Currently I have set as `11` but when its on first page on blog listing, because I have sliced/skipped first blog, its showing one less which is not correct ..

So my question is, how can I make this part proper and make sure it will show same number of maximum blogs on each page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, eventually I have resolved in this way ..

I put below code in my Blog CMS page ..

```
function onStart()
{       
    
    $latestPost = RainLab\Blog\Models\Post::isPublished()->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->first();
    $this->blogPosts->setProperty('exceptPost', $latestPost->id);
}
```

It will remove the first latest post from the blog list.

Thanks